# Is there a way to make background image without repeating for email in outlook.com?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

For normal webpages, it is easy to make an image to be covering a table row (or a div, which is usually not used in email.) For example,

```
tr {
    background-image: url('https://placehold.it/100x100');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve similar effect in email for outlook.com? (Please notice that it is outlook.com, not outlook client, so mso tag will not work.)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to avoid background images when coding mails - see: https://litmus.com/community/learning/25-understanding-background-images-in-email

Answer (score 1):

I use background images in HTML email all the time. The background-size: cover CSS attribute is not supported in a lot of email clients, including Outlook.com. As a work around, I recommend you to use a background image that fades in with the background color of the body tag. The image will have to be at least 950px wide in order to cover the reader screen in most email clients.The bg image can then be applied to a wrapper table container with a with of 100%. It will be centered as default. NOTE: For outlook desktop clients, you need to use the VML bg hack. More on that here https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds